# Removable device not showing up in Thunar

Tags: 18.04, usb, thunar

My microSD card (mounted at /var/host/media/removable/usb) does not appear properly under the "Devices" section of the Thunar side pane. It flickers briefly when mounting and unmounting as shown in [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bnsiLuN4-5ECOLsUyGzBSor-jcoEHrus) short video. It was mounting and appearing in Thunar perfectly fine in 16.04, but after I upgraded to 18.04, this started happening.

Launching Thunar from the console and plugging in the card results in these messages:

```
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "usb".
thunar-volman: Unsupported USB device type "ums-realtek".
thunar-volman: Unknown block device type "disk".
thunar-volman: Could not detect the volume corresponding to the device.
```

How can I get my device to show up normally in Thunar?

Edit: Forgot to mention I'm running Ubuntu using crouton on a Chromebook, so I wouldn't be surprised if this is an issue with that and I have to take this to the crouton forums. Just wanted to see if there was anything I could try in Ubuntu first.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, This is a confirmed issue existing in Thunar <  4.16.3.
(Also present in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Upgrade to 4.16.3+ to avoid the issue.

See here for details https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues/384